# set select dropdown value from database

Tags: php, html, sql

this is for my update profile page. i want to set the value of my dropdown menu depends on my database please check this

```
<select id="id" name="txtMInit">
   <option value="" selected>--</option>
      <?php
         $i = range('A','Z');
         foreach( $i as $val){
           echo "<option id='".$val."' 
           <?php if($val==$row['midI']){echo "selected";}?>>" .$val."."."</option>";
        }
      ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Is this not working in some way?  Please clarify, as we can't debug this for you.

Comment: You nested a PHP Tag inside a PHP tag which will error out.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Any errors? I mean, help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

I see error in this line :

```
echo "<option id='".$val."' <?php if($val==$row['midI']){echo "selected";}?>>" .$val."."."</option>";
```

This should help and is **concise** due to use of [Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) :

```
echo "<option id='" .$val ."'" .( $val == $row['midI'] ? " selected='selected' " : ' ' ) .">" .$val ."</option>";
```

Comment: No problem . If my answer solved your problem , please make sure you accept it so that it could be helpful to others who might come across similar problem . Cheers . . .

Comment: @Emilio Gort Thanks for inserting the link to Ternary operator .

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it:

```
<?php
$i = range('A','Z');
foreach( $i as $val){
    echo "<option id='".$val."'";
    if( $val == $row['midI'] ) echo " selected";
    echo ">".$val."</option>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the mistake

```
echo "<option id='".$val."' <?php if($val==$row['midI']){echo "selected";}?>>" .$val."."."</option>";
```

Change it to

```
$selected = "";
if($val==$row['midI']) {$selected="selected";}
echo "<option id='".$val."' ".$selected."  >" .$val."</option>";
```

Comment: user2805941, when you start understanding the flow, you can switch to more optimised expressions, like ( $val==$row['midI'] ? " selected='selected' " : ' ' )

Comment: Why is ternary "more optimised"?

Comment: because it takes less space